# I have an error when executing ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework

When I execute ionic serve, it shows the following errors:

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve this?

Comment: for what it's worth, the Ionic complier is getting better, and if you run into this issue today, the CLI (the terminal window) should show you the actual error instead of this message

Comment: The above comment has proved to be more valuable than any of the answers below!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error message.

Looking through the logs printed when doing

> ionic serve

showed me a bunch of errors, all similar to this

```
[ng] ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)

[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

[ng] Require stack:
```

This lead me to get the application up and running again by

> npm install node-sass --save

The compilation process is sometimes spitting out rather confusing error messages from time to time, but with a little digging one can start guessing where to start poking

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it. I fixed the routing file, I had a route that couldn't load because another route was higher order.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic include default favicon icon into index.html file.

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />
```

You can put your favicon icon into "assets/icon" and replace href above.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and it was because I had included an import I wasn't actually using.  In my example, I had accidently imported Console when using console.log.

I was getting error TS2307: Cannot find module 'console'. in the VS Code terminal, but my error in Chrome was "Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

So be aware that this error is not necessarily to do with the favicon.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but solved using below solution.

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico" />
```

I used **.ico** file instead of **.png** file and thats works for me. try once.

Answer (score 0):

I get same error multiple times,this error throw when u missed any small issue like wrong image path or forget to write import statement of any module/service/component.these error will shown in terminal when u running your project.After fixing these run your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
I advise you to take a look at your Terminal in VSCode (or the standard terminal if you launched it by there) and look for an ERROR message.

Most likely the problem isn't the favicon.ico blabla stuff but another element of your app, something in a .ts doc for example. Via Terminal you can seek for it in a better way than Chrome, that shows you this unrelated message.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same error .In my case i have done  mistake in importing file

**import { IUser } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/IUser**

> Changed path like below is fixed  error.

**import { IUser } from './shared/interfaces/IUser**

Cross check your import file. it might helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I downloaded a new branch of the project, I just run npm install of the lastest components

Answer (score 0):

I solved by created copy `favicon.png` from `assets/icon/favicon.png` to `root` project folder and rename it to `favicon.ico` , and also put it on  `assets/icon/favicon.ico`

and also check this answer .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749758/8370334

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with ionic v5 and angular v10.

You may have this error when you create some error in the `variables.scss` file.

I was using adding a list of global variable that will be used across the app but I forgot to add a `,`.

It didn't create an error while compiling...

The code was :

```
 $color-settings: (
  'primary': (
    'base': #297bfd,
  )  // <-- Comma is missing here
  'secondary': (
    'base': #297bfd,
  )
}
```

It will display the same error, I think, it breaks somehow the way ionic compile the scss.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after an upgrade. I solved the problem doing:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to change the browser, I fixed this clicking on the url resource which opened firefox and then I've been able to test the app normally on Firefox