# chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.1 kB [initial] [rendered] Cannot read property 'map' of undefined for angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

[image]

The above is the error I am getting. I am not able to resolve it because I am not getting in which file it is happening.

The following is my component.ts file:

```html
<div class="loginBody">
    <div class="login-page">
        <img src="./assets/logo.png" id="logo">
        <form [formGroup]="signin">

            <mat-form-field id="email">

                <input matInput placeholder="@meltwater.com" formControlName="emailFormControl">
                <mat-hint>Enter your email</mat-hint>
                <mat-error *ngIf="emailInput.hasError('email') && !emailInput.hasError('required')">
                    Please enter a valid email address
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <mat-form-field id="password">
                <input matInput placeholder="password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="passwordFormControl" required>
                <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-hint *ngIf="!passwordInput.value">Enter your password</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <mat-checkbox>Remember me</mat-checkbox>
            <br>
            <button id="loginButton" mat-raised-button routerLink='/login' routerLinkActive='active'>LOG IN</button>
            <br>
            <p class="message">Using company credentials? <a href="#"> Log in with SSO</a></p>
            <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is picture inserted is the error. I have not added any map element to any of my files.

The following is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AppliedInsightFrontend</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

This will be my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Following is the full error:

```
0% compiling
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activeℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 127 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 177 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-25T14:38:50.300Z - Hash: 5926a3d885deed4ad147 - Time: 3212ms

ERROR in Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Can you share full error message

Comment: yes i added  now the error to the end

Comment: Are you doing custom webpack configuration?

Comment: no i have not done that

Comment: If it possible can you share your repo?

Comment: i am not sure how to share repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210322/discussion-between-chellappan--and-ankita-basu).

Comment: Helpful advice: please use the Shift key at appropriate times when writing your question. Titles and sentences start with a capital letter. Some other words are naturally capitalised, such as the personal pronoun "I", as are proper nouns (like the names of languages and software systems).

Comment: yeah ok thankyou so much ,i will keep that in mind ,can you please look into the problem and help me please  :)

Comment: I think you need to apply some debugging technique here. If is possible, you should rollback your changes untill you reach a condition when the error disappears. A tiny step at a time, you start applying back your changes, and each time you look for the error. Thant helps you find the offending change, and that should give you a clue about the issue. Or you should put logs around the code of your last changes, and have a look at the logs before the error occurs. But the first one is much easier.

Comment: Check the code where you are using .map and check why the value is undefined, you might need to check if it an array before performing the action, It would be helpful for us if you share your component code (ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your chrome or your browser's debugger , select pause on caught exceptions. It will stop at this place where you are getting this error.

Better way to do it would be to enable source maps.
I am pretty sure the bundler that you are using would have support to generate javascript source maps. For angular I think you can find out how to enable source maps on the net, might be just a small config change. Enable it , build your application , run it on chrome and select pause on caught exceptions. It will stop at the exact line and it will show the file where this error has occured.

Don't forget to disable source maps for prod environments

Answer (score 0):

Many times, dependent components don't import everything they need.

Start with this: ng update @angular/material

If that doesn't work...
  Delete your npm cache (or the folder itself) in your project, and then type in npm install from the folder location of package.json.

If that doesn't work then you can attempt an ng update to latest version of (8 or 9).

If that doesn't work then you can try an npm update @angular/material@^X.Y.Y

Answer (score 0):

I solved by :

Looking for any response from `http` and get something known for angular  example

```
this.registerService.onRegister(data).subscribe(resp => {
            if (resp.header.httpStatus !== 200) {
                this.showErrors(resp.object);
                return;
            } 
            console.log(this.register);
        });
```

in this case `header` and `httpStatus` not known for angular i just added `// @ts-ignore` above it .

to be

```
 this.registerService.onRegister(data).subscribe(resp => {
              // @ts-ignore
                if (resp.header.httpStatus !== 200) {
                    this.showErrors(resp.object);
                    return;
                } 
                console.log(this.register);
            });
```

it's working for me